# spring webservice Invalid NamespaceHandler problem (jaxws)

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws, javabeans

I am building a web service with spring. I can build and deploy the project to tomcat but when the server starts up I am getting following error:

> Invalid NamespaceHandler class
>   [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler]
>   for namespace
>   [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: problem
>   with handler class file or dependent
>   class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport

I have already included the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar in my classpath.

My bean definition are here:

```
 <jaxws:endpoint id="helloWebservice"
  implementor="#com.xxx.impl.HelloWebserviceImpl"
  address="/hellows">
 </jaxws:endpoint>
```

My lib folder contains(WEB-INF/lib):

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asinus-api.jar
asinus-ri.jar
aspectjrt.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
backport-util-concurrent-3.0.jar
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.6.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
com.springsource.javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-core-1.7.2.jar
ezmorph-1.0.4.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
javassist.jar
jdom.jar
jpa-api-2.0-cr-1.jar
json-lib-2.2.jar
jta-spec1_0_1.jar
lib.txt
log4j-1.2.15.jar
memcached-2.4.2.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
owasp.jar
quartz-1.7.3.jar
rome-1.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-modules-cache.jar
```

and my external jars:

```
cxf-2.2.5.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar
geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar
geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar
neethi-2.0.4.jar
saaj-api-1.3.jar
saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wss4j-1.5.8.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar
xmlsec-1.4.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar
```

Comment: Hi dds, Were you able to resolve this issue ?
I am having the same problem with JBoss 5.1, Spring 3.0.3 and Mule embedded inside webapp. -Om

Comment: hi, yes I overcame this error but unfortunately I forgot how to do it :(

Comment: By adding <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxws.xml" /> to your beans.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that either you are missing a spring jar, or you have an older version of it. Try to get the latest `spring-beans.jar` on the classpath. Also make sure there isn't another such jar on the classpath that's older.

Comment: I have com.springframework.beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar is that the one you talking about..

Comment: well I have download and replace beans.jar but the error remains the same. any other idea?

Comment: @dds then check if there isn't another such jar, that's older. Better - give the directory structure of your lib folder

Comment: @Bozho I havent seen any lib duplicate. I have edit my question to show my lib folder. can you see anything wrong?

Comment: actually it is external jar added to my classpath, the first list I gave was the WEB-INF/lib folder. Now I added the external jars..

Comment: Well, all seems fine. Clean-build, redeploy.. and see again. And make sure the mentionted class is indeed in the beans jar (browse it with rar)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consideration. I have verified the jar and cleaned-rebuild-redeployed smoothly. But when the server starts up the error still sits there...

Comment: anyone got solution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have stumbled on this error too, and it really got on my nerves. So, without further due

> environment:
>
> Wildfly 20.0.1.Final
>
> Java 11

objectives:

I just want to add cxf so that I could use cxf - spring descriptors (in particular jaxws:endpoint) in my applicationContext.xml, i.e

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <!-- one or more jaxws:endpoint POJO declarations -->
    <jaxws:endpoint id="POJOEndpoint" address="/test" implementor="com.test.myRandomPojoEndpoint">
        <jaxws:invoker>
            <bean class="org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.InvokerJSE"/>
        </jaxws:invoker>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

issue:

but all I get is

> Invalid NamespaceHandler class
> [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace
> [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: problem with handler class file or
> dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport

Solution:

before you begin you **SHOULD KNOW** that for this stuff to work you have to **INSTALL SPRING LIBRARIES** to your wildfly application server and so...

The list of spring libraries in my wildfly environment:

```
spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-jcl-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Installation path is as follows

**wildfly-20.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\springframework\spring\main**

just put spring libraries in this path and add module.txt (that same folder as spring libraries) as follows

module.txt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2010, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->
<module name="org.springframework.spring" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-expression-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-jcl-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.reactivestreams" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="javaee.api"/>
            <module name="javax.api" export="true" />
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
            <module name="org.jboss.vfs" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

**======THE END==========**

NOTES:

So, if that is so simple why did I fail? WHY?

At first I installed spring libraries in

**wildfly-20.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\spring\main**

and that cause a lot of misery, because

if you looked at
**wildfly-20.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\cxf\impl\main\module.xml**, you would see that it has a dependency on spring, i.e

```
    <module name="org.springframework.spring" optional="true">
        <imports>
            <include path="META-INF"/>
        </imports>
    </module>
```

however, I installed spring libraries under different name which was **org.spring** and not **org.springframework.spring**, so that was the root of my failure.

my jboss-deployment-structure.xml (in WEB-INF folder) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.springframework.spring">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Related threads (to name a few)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033999/jboss-eap-7-exclude-webservices-subsystem-gives-noclassdeffounderror-failed-to

http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/using-spring-cxf-descriptors-in-wildfly

http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/using-spring-cxf-descriptors-in-wildfly

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html
```

Hope it helps other lost souls.