# JBoss EAP 7 exclude webservices subsystem gives NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl

Tags: java, spring, jboss, cxf, jboss-eap-7

In Jboss EAP7 I have added cxf maven dependencies in pom.xml and excluded webservices subsystem in **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** since want to use my own version of cxf defined in pom.xml. But get below exception during server start up-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/jaxws/spring/EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl (Module "deployment.SomeApplication.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl (Module "deployment.SomeApplication.war:main" from Service Module Loader): javax/xml/ws/Endpoint
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/jaxws/spring/EndpointDefinitionParser$SpringEndpointImpl (Module "deployment.SomeApplication.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl (Module "deployment.SomeApplication.war:main" from Service Module Loader): javax/xml/ws/Endpoint
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser.<clinit>(EndpointDefinitionParser.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler.init(NamespaceHandler.java:36)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
    ... 30 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        <subsystem name="webservices" />
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

**Update:**
Installed Spring module in JBoss and updated jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Picket link configuration -->
            <module name="org.picketlink" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.springframework.spring" export="true" meta-inf="export"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" export="true" />  
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true" />  
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
            <subsystem name="weld" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now see below error-

```
17:04:02,317 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) 

MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."abc_code_formatting.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."abc_code_formatting.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "abc_code_formatting.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFServlet (Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" from local module loader @116af24 (finder: local module finder @e82894 (roots: D:\tools\jboss-eap-7.0.2\modules,D:\tools\jboss-eap-7.0.2\modules\system\layers\base\.overlays\layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.2.CP,D:\tools\jboss-eap-7.0.2\modules\system\layers\base))): org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who is facing above issue. Here is the solution. Add below dependency in pom/classpath-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

javax.xml.ws.Endpoint is available in JBoss modules jar. During deployment conflict arises since it's in a different module and you've removed webservices dependency so webapp classloader doesn't see it (I'm assuming classloader look up hierarchy is another issue here since this class is available as part of JDK, ideally JBoss should have honored JDK classpath).

Answer (score 1):

jboss-deployment-struture.xml should be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.antlr"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is using spring and therefore, are you sure you have installed the spring custom module in EAP 7 and have a dependency included in **jboss-deployment-struture.xml** file ? so that the required class definition can be found ?

As a reference, you can refer to this link, 
[Spring module in JBoss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098684/spring-module-in-jboss-7)

Also, make sure **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** has a dependency on this module as below.

```
<module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF**"/>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf**"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
```

Comment: I have spring dependencies included in pom.xml. Is there any way i can avoid configuration change (install spring custom module) in jboss and indicate jboss to use spring from the classpath?

Comment: Viral, I have installed spring module in jboss and updated jboss-deployment-structure.xml but still see NoClassDefFoundError for org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener. Updated the post with stacktrace.

Comment: Also if I add module dependencies as you mentioned org.apache.cxf and org.apache.cxf.impl won't I be using JBoss CXF jars?